# IIS Virtual Directory And Content-Range Header

Tags: iis, microsoft-bits

I have created a virtual directory in IIS to serve some files over https (this virtual directory is pointing to a location on the disk with some files). I've enabled directory browsing and I am able to download the files.
When I try to use BITS to download, I am able to download fine when setting the BITS job priority to 'foreground'.
But when I set the priority to anything other than 'foreground' BITS throws an error "The server does not support the necessary HTTP protocol. BITS requires that the server support the Range protocol header"
I believe I have narrowed it down to the lack of the 'Content-Range' response header after reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/http-requirements-for-bits-downloads
How do I ensure this response header is set when BITS is requesting partial chunks of the file?

Comment: Do you mean how to set the Content-Range response header in IIS？If so, you can add custom HTTP response headers in the HTTP Response Headers module. Name: Content-Range,
Value: bytes